# Failed to pull image "docker.io/jboss/keycloak" failed to pull image, pull access denied

Tags: docker, keycloak, kubernetes-helm

We are using keycloak as the auth server (helm chart on K8S), deployments were working just fine until today (Mar 20th 2024), an upgrade was triggered that required to restart the pod, and started to see the below error:

```
Failed to pull image "docker.io/jboss/keycloak:<version>": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/jboss/keycloak:<version>": failed to resolve reference "docker.io/jboss/keycloak:<version>": pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed
```

When I tried to lookup the docker hub registry for the image, I got that this image is no longer exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be that jboss/keycloak team had a very old plans to move from dockerhub to quay.io, so in case you faced such issue you just need to update your resources that reference repository `docker.io/jboss/keycloak` to be `quay.io/keycloak/keycloak` and everything should work normally.

Hope this save you in your production env or even better prevent any potential downtime.